# Next JS parallel routes don't work, getting 404

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes, modal-dialog

I'm trying to setup a basic Modal using parallel routes in Next 13 (app directory). Here is my file structure:

```
app
├── @create_recipe
│   ├── default.jsx
│   ├── page.jsx
├── layout.jsx
├── page.jsx
├── default.jsx
```

```
// layout.jsx
<ClerkProvider>
      <TanstackProvider>
        <html lang='en relative'>
          <body>
            <div className='absolute p-2'>
              <UserButton afterSignOutUrl='/' />
            </div>
            {props.children}
            {props.create_recipe}
          </body>
        </html>
      </TanstackProvider>
    </ClerkProvider>
```

But when I navigate to `localhost:3000/create_recipe` it shows me the Next.js 404 page.

Is there some experimental flag I need to enable?

The `page.jsx` inside the parallel route just renders a `hello world` element and both default.js return null

Folder structure:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Parallel Routes

The `@create_recipe` is already defined as `slots` with the `@folder_name` convention.

And here's what the documentation says.

```
Slots are not route segments and do not affect the URL structure. 
The file path /@team/members would be accessible at /members.
```

Therefore, when you try to access the slot with the url `localhost:3000/create_recipe`, it's an expected behavior that the app redirects you to the 404 page.

#### 2. default.jsx

from your question,

```
The page.jsx inside the parallel route just renders a hello world element 
and both default.js return null.
```

Think the default route as a fallback content when Next.js cannot recover the slot's active state based on the current URL.

If `default.jsx` returned null (I don't know from where but), that means the Next.js was able to find the slot and render it.

For instance, imagine if you imported `@a` and `@b` as slots in `app/layout.js` and navigated to `/innerRoute` when only `@a` has `@a/innerRoute`, then the Next.js will render `@b/default.js` for `@b`'s portion.

---

#### Added

I use the same `layout.js` structure, and this is `app/members/page.js`
[image: app/members/page.js]

as you can see, the `@create_recipe/members` page is rendered inside `/members` route because of the `app/layout.js` structure.

[image]

It would be more helpful for me to figure out what happened if you could write on what route it renders the `hello world` element, and about the element as well.

Check [the Parallel Routes Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/parallel-routes) for more.

---

### Added on Oct 24th

Your comment

> I think we're almost there, but something isn't right still. I updated
> the question with a screenshot of my folder structure. Despite having
> a page.js and default.js in the root of @create_recipe, I never see
> the hello world render out on the / route. What I want is to be on /,
> click a link to/create-recipe/ and have that route's contents render
> on top of the current route, just like a modal would. I can handle the
> styling. I just don't want it to navigate away from the parent route

I get your point and here's my point.

1. "click a link to/create-recipe/" changes the window history
2. "I just don't want it to navigate away from the parent route": IMO, this creates a paradox because when a user clicks the link to `create-recipe`, the browser navigates to the route.
3. What about using a [shallow routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#shallow-routing) and query param for instance, `website.com/?create-recipe=a`

And refactor the `create-recipe` page as a component, and render it inside the root route if the query param meets the condition, also you can control other options as query params.

Comment: I think we're almost there, but something isn't right still. I updated the question with a screenshot of my folder structure. Despite having a page.js and default.js in the root of @create_recipe, I never see the `hello world` render out on the `/` route. 

What I want is to be on `/`, click a link to`/create-recipe`/ and have that route's contents render _on top_ of the current route, just like a modal would. I can handle the styling. I just don't want it to navigate away from the parent route

Comment: @MarcFletcher added my response to the original answer.